# Automation: Create a ticket on Monday where Friday is the first day of the month

Tags: jira, jira-automation

Is there a way to setup a job in Jira automation so that every Monday it checks if the Friday of that week is the first Friday of the month that the Friday falls on? If so, the automation will create a ticket. I know how to have it setup a cron job to check on Monday and create a ticket, but I'm not sure how to have it check if the Friday of that week is the first Friday of that month.

Example

1. Monday might be 11/27, but the Friday is 12/1 so it would be the first Friday of the month that Friday falls on, but the script needs to check on Monday because that's the day the ticket will be created, or Monday might be 01/01 and Friday is 01/05, etc..